# Can you conditionally write to multiple files at the same level?

Tags: c#, log4net

I know you can configure Log4Net to write to multiple files that are different levels. Is it possible to write conditionally to multiple files at the same level?

For example:

```
<root>
  <appender-ref ref="ErrorAppender" />
  <appender-ref ref="DailyAppender" />
  <appender-ref ref="SuperSecretAppender" />
</root>
```

Levels:

> ErrorAppender = ERROR
>   
> DailyAppender = INFO
>   
> SuperSecretAppender = INFO

So right now I log all errors to ErrorAppender and daily info logging to the DailyAppender.  Now I want to add another file SuperSecretAppender that I will only append in a certain instance (and do not want the contents that are going into the DailyAppender).

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you just want to have a separate file that you can log to without being bothered by what the root logger is hooked up to. If so, use a separate logger, not a separate appender (well, use a separate appender too, but use it only for that logger). Make the logger non-additive (`additivity='false'`) so its messages don't go to the root logger.